# Git showing every changed file not folders

Tags: 7, version-control

Git is showing every change in every installed module folder. This makes it unusable because I can't see what I'm committing.

Previously git only showed the module folders. So if i installed Views, it would show me in 
`git status`, untracked files "`sites/all/modules/views`"

I used git -rm to remove a file, but somehow it managed to completely mess this up and now it shows every single changed file. Here's the bottom part of my latest `git status`, it's so long most of it is untrackable.

[image]

What have I done, how can I change this back to what I had before, because I really need to roll back a commit.

EDIT:

Context for my problem, now having the solution.

Some modules in Drupal have a huge number of files. When you add them to the index, git lists all the files in the folder rather than each individual one.

In the case of some modules, in my case the commerce and jquery_update modules this will probably add more files than your command line shell can display, so you won't be able to see everything.

I got around this by removing the modules from my index with `git reset HEAD *filepath*`

and then adding them in separate commits.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about git rather than Drupal. This is not a Drupal specific issue and would be more appropriate on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between showing the folder level for untracked files and the file level for tracked files is expected git behavior. This will always be the case. Once you add the folder (which adds all the files in it) each of the files is tracked by git and will be tracked individually. So, when you do a status, it SHOULD list each file separately. Yes, this is kind of annoying, but the general idea is that you'll add a folder and then commit that change. Once committed, you won't see each file unless is has been changed in some way.

As for fixing the situation, you probably haven't actually messed anything up; it's just tough to see that because there are so many new files in your index (a git term which you can research if you'd like more information).

If you'd like to undo it all, you can run the [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html) command. In general, most things related to git can be demystified with a couple of Google searches. If you're new to git, I recommend the free [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: Thanks very much for that, by chance I'd not added modules which had huge numbers of files before and I'd never quite grasped that particular nuance of git. (I thought the problem might have been more common in Drupal and the context was Drupal thus the posting here.)